# Strange error in flask:

Tags: python, datetime, flask, werkzeug

The following code (edited this based on the first answer):

```
time_difference_in_seconds = int(
    (datetime.combine(date.today(), max_time)
     - datetime.combine(date.today(), min_time)
).total_seconds())
[...]
for date in dates:
[...]
```

gives me this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'date' referenced before assignment
```

Just to be clear, I have imported date and datetime from datetime. Moreover, when I execute the code in the werkzeug debugger, it works just fine and gives me the desired result:

```
[console ready]
>>> int((datetime.combine(date.today(), max_time)
        - datetime.combine(date.today(), min_time)).total_seconds())
46800
```

In fact, I have used the same function in different views, and it doesn't cause any errors there.

What causes this strange error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Ben: Post the rest of the function which contains this line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning some value to `date` later in the function, wich caused Python to consider `date` as a reference to the local variable instead of the imported module you expected

Rename this `date` variable inside the function to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem indeed. Thanks! Changing that fixed the problem. That was a pretty novice-y mistake, in hindsight.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you must assign something to `date` in your function like this:

```
def somefunc():
    time_difference_in_seconds = int(
        (datetime.combine(date.today(), max_time)
         - datetime.combine(date.today(), min_time)
    ).total_seconds())
    date = ...
```

renaming the variable will resolve this problem.